# How can I include fast.ai functionality when primarily using PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, fast-ai

I am using PyTorch to carry out vision tasks, but would like to use some of what fast.ai provides since it has a lot of useful functionality. I'd prefer to work mostly in PyTorch since it's easier for me to understand what's going on, it's easier for me to find information on it online, and I want to maintain flexibility.

In https://docs.fast.ai/migrating_pytorch it's written that after I use the following imports: `from fastai.vision.all import *` and `from migrating_pytorch import *`, I should be able to start "Incrementally adding fastai goodness to your PyTorch models", which sounds great.
But when I run the second import I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'migrating_pytorch'`. Searching in https://github.com/fastai/fastai I also don't find any code mention of migrating_pytorch.py, nor did I manage to find something online.
(I'm using fast.ai version 2.3.1)

I'd like to know if this is indeed the way to go, and if so how to get it working. Or if there's a better way then how I should use that approach instead.

As an example, it would be nice if I could use the EarlyStoppingCallback, SaveModelCallback, and add some metrics from fast.ai instead of writing them myself, while still having everything in mostly "native" PyTorch.

Preferably the solution isn't specific to vision only, but that's my current need.

Comment: I'm aware that PyTorch-Ignite (and likely others as well) has some or all of the functionality examples I mentioned, but it seems that fast.ai has more functionality that I found useful and was easier for me to work with.

Answer (score 0):

migrating_pytorch is an example script. It's in the fast.ai repo at: https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/nbs/examples/migrating_pytorch.py

The notebook that shows how to use it is at: https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/827e7cc0fad2db06c40df393c9569309377efac0/nbs/examples/migrating_pytorch.ipynb

For the callback example. Your training code would end up looking something like:

```
cbs = [EarlyStoppingCallback(), SaveModelCallback()]
learner = Learner(dls, simple_cnn(), loss_func=F.cross_entropy, cbs=cbs)
learner.fit(1)
```

Those two callbacks probably need some arguments, e.g. save path, etc.